# Maintain state with secured cookies in http protocol

Tags: java, http, servlets, cookies

Is it possible to maintain session with http protocol using secured cookies? When secured cookies are used, the browser does not send the secured cookies and hence maintaining state is bit difficult.

Comment: Actually, what you are asking is very contradictory. If you want the cookies to be sent over HTTP then why do you need Secured Cookies.

Comment: We want the tomcat settings to be unchanged and since the applications running inside tomcat already uses http, and our security is generating secured cookies, we are facing difficulties in maintaining session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using secure cookies over HTTP is not possible. The purpose of secure cookies is that they are **only** allowed to be transfered over **HTTPS**.

Comment: Then can we somehow still maintain session ? May be server side hack or something ?

Comment: @user2354566 Yes, use HTTPS, use unsecured cookies, or add a parameter in the URL, like web containers do with `jsessionid`. But your combination HTTP+secure cookies is not possible.

Comment: Thanks a ton !! The different solution you have mentioned were known. However since our application is already in production and we do not want to change any tomcat settings I preferred asking alternatives. Appreciate you quick response :)